# .htaccess map domain to a subfolder inside public_html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an apache server for the system [https://theveganhut.co.uk](http://theveganhut.co.uk) ; I need to have different sites in the same server. So, I put the files for http://theveganhut.co.uk in a folder `theveganhut.co.uk` in the `public_html` folder.

I have mapped the domain [theveganhut.co.uk](http://theveganhut.co.uk) to the folder `theveganhut.co.uk` via the `.htaccess` file in the root(`public_html`)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?theveganhut.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/theveganhut.co.uk/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /theveganhut.co.uk/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?theveganhut.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /theveganhut.co.uk/ [L]
```

But when I load the url http://theveganhut.co.uk/admin , the admin login page is seen, but the URL changes to http://theveganhut.co.uk/theveganhut.co.uk/admin/. I want the url to be http://theveganhut.co.uk/admin/

Is there something I am missing in the .htaccess file to address this issue? Please help.

Comment: I would recommend just changing the document root in your virtual host configuration for apache, rather than using .htaccess and rewrite rules.  On production sites, I tend to turn off allowoverride by setting it to none (to stop the use off .htaccess), this removes unnecessary directory scanning/disk IO.  And instead place rewrite rules in the virtual host configuration (if needed).

Comment: Where can we do that? Is it an option in the cpanel?

Comment: Cpanel config is abnormal.  You may want to search for changing document root under cpanel.  But be careful this won't affect any other domains or automated procedures - such as backing up.